# How to deal with state "Exit 0" in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, exit, entry-point, docker-container

I have build a Docker image and afterwards run a container using Docker Compose. The following command will do the job for me:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I have restarted the PC and now I want to start the previous container that I've created before. So I have tried the following command:

```
$ docker-compose start 
Starting php-apache ... done
```

Apparently it works but it doesn't as per the output for the following command:

```
$ docker-compose ps
          Name                         Command               State    Ports 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
php55devwork_php-apache_1   /bin/sh -c bash -C '/usr/l ...   Exit 0
```

For sure something is wrong and I am trying to find out what.

- How do I find why the command is failing?
- Is there any place where I could see a log file or something that help me to identify and fix the error?

[Here is](https://github.com/reypm/php55-dev) the repository if you want to give it a try.

**Update**

If I remove the container: `docker rm <container-id>` and recreate it by running `docker-compose up -d --build` it works again.

**Update #1**

I am not able to see such weird characters:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look into your Docker github and [`setup_php_settings`](https://github.com/reypm/php55-dev/blob/master/container-files/usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings)
on line (line n. 27) there is `source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND`

and that runs `apache2` on foreground so it shouldn't exit with status `code 0`.

<strike>But it seems to me like your `setup_php_settings` contains some weird character (when I run your image with compose) 
*(original is one on right side)* [weird character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB3Dz.jpg)
I have **changed it to new lines** and it worked for me. Let us know if it helped.</strike>

If you want to debug your docker container you can run it without entrypoint like:

`docker run -it yourImage bash`

---

***-- AFTER some investigation:***

There were still some errors when I restart docker container - like in your case stopped container and start after reboot. There were problems: symbolic links already exist and apache2 has grumpy PID so we need to do something like in [***oficial php docker***](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/7.0/apache/apache2-foreground#L13)

This is full `setup_php_settings` worked for me after container restart.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
set -e

PHP_ERROR_REPORTING=${PHP_ERROR_REPORTING:-"E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE"}
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
sed -ri "s/^error_reporting\s*=.*$//g" /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
echo "error_reporting = $PHP_ERROR_REPORTING" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/uploads
mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/sessions
mkdir -p /data/tmp/php/xdebug

chown -R www-data:www-data /data/tmp/php*

ln -sf /etc/php5/mods-available/zz-php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zz-php.ini
ln -sf /etc/php5/mods-available/zz-php-directories.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/zz-php-directories.ini

# Add symbolic link to get Zend out of the current install dir
ln -sf /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/ /usr/share/php/Zend

a2enmod rewrite
php5enmod mcrypt

# Apache gets grumpy about PID files pre-existing
: "${APACHE_PID_FILE:=${APACHE_RUN_DIR:=/var/run/apache2}/apache2.pid}"
rm -f "$APACHE_PID_FILE"

source /etc/apache2/envvars && exec /usr/sbin/apache2 -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

Comment: That's odd. I am not seeing them, which tool did you use? I am in Fedora using Atom editor. Regarding the errors should them stop the container from start?

Comment: I have updated the OP with an image, I am not able to see those weird characters

Comment: TurtoiseGit but I am on Windows. As I saw you have figured it out but it's weird.

Comment: @ReynierPM It is probably windows error. But when I restart container It exited with error like in your case

Comment: @ReynierPM  I added `setup_php_settings` that worked for me also after I did restart of container without rebuild.

Answer (score 16):

This is what helped me to resolve this issue:
Under one of your services in the docker-compose yaml file, type in the following:

`tty: true` so it'll look like

```yaml
version: '3'

services: 
   web: 
     tty: true
```

Hopefully this helps someone; thumps up if it helps you :)

Comment: Wasted 2h to find how to setup an ubuntu container because of exit code 0 and this silved the issue, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can check logs with `docker compose logs`.

Looking through your repo, you have

```
ENTRYPOINT bash -C '/usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings';'bash'
```

which, without an interactive session, bash will exit immediately (with an exit code 0) after reading the end of file on stdin.

Comment: I believe that's the issue but I don't know how to fix it, could you help me to fix this issue? I am starting to learn Docker :-)

Comment: The entrypoint needs to not exit, so `ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings && sleep infinity` may work.

Answer (score 2):

Normally getting an `exit 0` should be a reason to celebrate, as it indicates that your command has ended successfully (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Having had a look at your `Dockerfile` it looks like, your just invoking `bash` in your entry point which then for sure will exit (as it is non blocking). In order to serve some data, you should rather be calling `php` (which is a blocking operation that keeps the container up), like done in the official docker files for php (see the `CMD ["php", "-a"]` at https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/1c56325a69718a3e3cf76179e75d070b7e23da62/5.6/Dockerfile)

Comment: Should I modify my `ENTRYPOIN`T to be `ENTRYPOINT bash -C '/usr/local/bin/setup_php_settings';'php -a'` instead? Is that what you said?

Comment: Jup, but be sure also to try what VladoDemcak has found out.